# Updating views in AdapterView while visible

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapterview

I have a set of data which I want to display to the user in an AdapterView, which I will also want to change at runtime while the view is being displayed. How do I have the view for the object whose data has changed redisplay itself?

For example, I have a set of books, which the user can download, and I want to display books that are being downloaded in addition to books present. I want to update the download progress for the user to view in real time.

In this case, how should I notify my view that it needs to be updated? Should I have a callback on the view itself, or should I invalidate the AdapterView? If I have a callback on the view, I want to be careful not to cause any leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do `notifyDataSetChanged` to force the View to update (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) and that should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks. The problem there is that this forces a refresh of all views. Is there any way to limit this to only having one view redraw itself? Or am I trying to overdesign this?

Comment: Well, its possible but because `ListView`s reuse individual rows it would be a little tricky. I'm guessing you could possibly tag each row with a key to the associated data in your adapter's `getView` implementation and then search through the `ListView`s child views for the matching row and just invalidate that row. HOWEVER, I believe that the `ListView` is already smart enough to only refresh the views currently visible on screen, so its probably not worth the bother.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Do I need to call `myViewList.requestLayout`? Maybe it's because `myAdapter.getItem` is nullfied?